# SingleColumnValueFilter not returning proper number of rows

Tags: filter, mapreduce, hbase

In our HBase table, each row has a column called crawl identifier. Using a MapReduce job, we only want to process at any one time rows from a given crawl. In order to run the job more efficiently we gave our scan object a filter that (we hoped) would remove all rows except those with the given crawl identifier. However, we quickly discovered that our jobs were not processing the correct number of rows.

I wrote a test mapper to simply count the number of rows with the correct crawl identifier, without any filters. It iterated over all the rows in the table and counted the correct, expected number of rows (~15000). When we took that same job, added a filter to the scan object, the count dropped to ~3000. There was no manipulation of the table itself during or in between these two jobs.

Since adding the scan filter caused the visible rows to change so dramatically, we expect that we simply built the filter incorrectly.

Our MapReduce job features a single mapper:

```
public static class RowCountMapper extends TableMapper<ImmutableBytesWritable, Put>{

    public String crawlIdentifier;

    // counters
    private static enum CountRows {
        ROWS_WITH_MATCHED_CRAWL_IDENTIFIER
    }

    @Override
    public void setup(Context context){
        Configuration configuration=context.getConfiguration();
        crawlIdentifier=configuration.get(ConfigPropertyLib.CRAWL_IDENTIFIER_PROPERTY);

    }

    @Override
    public void map(ImmutableBytesWritable legacykey, Result row, Context context){
        String rowIdentifier=HBaseSchema.getValueFromRow(row, HBaseSchema.CRAWL_IDENTIFIER_COLUMN);
        if (StringUtils.equals(crawlIdentifier, rowIdentifier)){
            context.getCounter(CountRows.ROWS_WITH_MATCHED_CRAWL_IDENTIFIER).increment(1l);
        }
    }
}
```

The filter setup is like this:

```
String crawlIdentifier=configuration.get(ConfigPropertyLib.CRAWL_IDENTIFIER_PROPERTY);
if (StringUtils.isBlank(crawlIdentifier)){
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Crawl Identifier not set.");
}

// build an HBase scanner
Scan scan=new Scan();
SingleColumnValueFilter filter=new SingleColumnValueFilter(HBaseSchema.CRAWL_IDENTIFIER_COLUMN.getFamily(),
    HBaseSchema.CRAWL_IDENTIFIER_COLUMN.getQualifier(),
    CompareOp.EQUAL,
    Bytes.toBytes(crawlIdentifier));
filter.setFilterIfMissing(true);
scan.setFilter(filter);
```

Are we using the wrong filter, or have we configured it wrong?

EDIT: we're looking at manually adding all the column families as per https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-2198 but I'm pretty sure the Scan includes all the families by default.

Comment: Can you also show the original mapper in which you manually did the filtering?

Comment: It was the same mapper; the only difference is that I didn't assign a Filter to the scan object (in the second block of code.) Of course, what you refer to as manual filtering is simply the if() block in the map() method.

Comment: @whiterook6 - did you ever resolve this? thx

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea. This was almost two years ago; I can't remember.

Answer (score 0):

The filter looks correct, but under certain conditions one scenario that could cause this relates to character encodings.  Your Filter is using Bytes.toBytes(String) which uses UTF8 [1], whereas you *might* be using native character encoding in HBaseSchema or when you write the record if you use String.getBytes()[2].  Check that the crawlIdentifier was originally written to HBase using the following to ensure the filter is comparing like for like in the filtered scan.

```
Bytes.toBytes(crawlIdentifier)
```

[1] http://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/util/Bytes.html#toBytes(java.lang.String)
[2] http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes()

Comment: A while ago we did find a bug relating to this very issue. We burned a swath of code looking for String.toBytes() and replace them all. The code to write the crawl Identifier was written correctly.