# SingleColumnValueFilter has no impact on result

Tags: java, hbase

hy,

this question is pretty similar to [SingleColumnValueFilter not returning proper number of rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10935901/singlecolumnvaluefilter-not-returning-proper-number-of-rows) .

I use four SingleColumnValueFilter's w/ operator EQUAL and add them to a FilterList with Operator MUST_PASS_ONE. the number of results is the same as w/o setting the FilterList. The value to compare is a byte[] that should be correct as I just store the values from previous results. (it is an IP address that I convert to InetAddress, new InetAddress(value as byte[]), when retrieving the data, and for the query described I just call InetAddress.getAddress which returns a byte[])

Do you have any ideas what might be the problem? Am I using the Filter wrong?

EDIT:

I also used the original values retrieved by the query as value for SingleColumnValueFilter, and there was no difference in the results, thus the byte[] contents can't be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think I can give the answer myself, sorry for not debugging and checking all the hbase code before.

I just checked the implementation of the compare algorithm (which is lexicographically), and thus i realized that the length is not taken into account, though I thought it would be filled up w/ zero's; unfortunately it is not.

The only reasonable option would be to create a custom comparator (eg see [How do you use a custom comparator with SingleColumnValueFilter on HBase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577142/how-do-you-use-a-custom-comparator-with-singlecolumnvaluefilter-on-hbase))

Comment: I'm sorry this doesn't make any sense to me (I guess I don't enough about hbase).  How does Lexicographical comparison impact EQUALS?  I can see it impacting, LESS, GREATER (specially if you're comparing string version of numbers) but it should have no impact on equals...could you please explain?

Comment: I had two byte[] of different length. I debugged the code and realized that the compare algorithm returned when it reached the length of the shorter one and ignored the rest of the longer byte[], as if it wasn't there. and the returned value was not the expected one (which should've been 'false') I hope I remember correctly. (the version used back then was 0.92.1 if I'm not mistaken) I can check again and get back in a couple of days probably...it could also be that there were unlucky test data involved!

Comment: Thank you very much @divadpoc, this clarifies it somewhat.  I'm having  suffering from the same symptoms as your problem...but not sure if the issue is related.